# update firebase realtimeDatabase but in BottomDialog Fragment ? and also in Material Toggle group buttons

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-togglebutton

I write a code for BottomDialogFragment
But the issue is when someone chooses 10₹ the program run like a loop and subtract money from his wallet continously untill it will be **0**.

Main issue that was when user clicks on join that was executed continously but I never used the Loop for the code please resolve this issue I'm not able to figure out the issue

Here is My **BottomRedFragment.java**

```
public class BottomRedFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    FragmentBottomRedBinding binding;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
//    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
//    DatabaseReference price;

    int quantity = 1;
    String coin;
    int icoin = 0;
    String mobile;

    int ivalue;
    int tcmoney;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentBottomRedBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        String qty = String.valueOf(quantity);
        binding.quantityRed.setText(qty);

        mobile = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile");

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setTitle("Joining Red");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");

        MaterialButtonToggleGroup toggleGroup = binding.toggleButton;
        int buttonId = toggleGroup.getCheckedButtonId();
        MaterialButton button = toggleGroup.findViewById(buttonId);
        toggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener(new MaterialButtonToggleGroup.OnButtonCheckedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onButtonChecked(MaterialButtonToggleGroup group, int checkedId, boolean isChecked) {

                if (group.getCheckedButtonId() == R.id.btn1) {

                    icoin = 10;
                    int ten = icoin * quantity;
                    coin = String.valueOf(ten);
                    binding.totalPriceMoney.setText(coin);
                } else if (group.getCheckedButtonId() == R.id.btn2) {

                    icoin = 50;
                    int fifty = icoin * quantity;
                    coin = String.valueOf(fifty);
                    binding.totalPriceMoney.setText(coin);
                } else if (group.getCheckedButtonId() == R.id.btn3) {

                    icoin = 100;
                    int hundred = icoin * quantity;
                    coin = String.valueOf(hundred);
                    binding.totalPriceMoney.setText(coin);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Choose a valid amount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        binding.subtractRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                decrement();
            }
        });
        binding.addRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                increment();
            }
        });

        binding.joinRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tcmoney = Integer.parseInt(binding.totalPriceMoney.getText().toString());
                if (tcmoney == 0 || icoin == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please choose Correct Values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    progressDialog.show();
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    joinVerify();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void joinVerify() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), mobile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mobile).child("wallet");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                ivalue = Integer.parseInt(value);

                if (tcmoney > ivalue) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Insufficient Funds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    int ijoin = ivalue - tcmoney;
                    String join = String.valueOf(ijoin);

                    databaseReference.setValue(join);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Joined Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });


    }

    private void increment() {
        quantity++;
        String s = String.valueOf(quantity);
        binding.quantityRed.setText(s);

        int calc = icoin * quantity;
        coin = String.valueOf(calc);
        binding.totalPriceMoney.setText(coin);

    }

    private void decrement() {
        quantity = quantity > 1 ? --quantity : 1;
        String s = String.valueOf(quantity);
        binding.quantityRed.setText(s);

        int calc = icoin * quantity;
        coin = String.valueOf(calc);
        binding.totalPriceMoney.setText(coin);

    }

}
```

Here is my **fragment_bottom_red.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".Fragments.BottomRedFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/red_a700"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="red"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"

            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CONTRACT MONEY"
            android:textColor="@color/red_a700"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:singleSelection="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:text="₹10"
                android:textColor="@color/red_a700" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="₹50"
                android:textColor="@color/red_a700" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="₹100"
                android:textColor="@color/red_a700" />

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/subtractRed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/red_a700"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantityRed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addRed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/red_a700"
                android:text="+"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="Total order money is ₹"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalPriceMoney"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/joinRed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#B71C1C"
            android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"
            android:paddingStart="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="50dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Join"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
            android:text="By clicking JOIN Button you \n agree to our presale rule"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo No It was not give any error but show me this toast **Insufficient Funds** due to make condition in `joinVeriy()` method

for example: a user have 300₹ in his wallet in firebase realtime database and he choose 50₹ of 3 coins means 50*3 = 150 subtracted from his wallet that stores in realtime database but the code executes until condition is false that his wallet amount is less than order value or ==0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnDataChange() keep calling each time you update value in Realtime Database.

```
binding.joinRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tcmoney = Integer.parseInt(binding.totalPriceMoney.getText().toString());
                if (tcmoney == 0 || icoin == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please choose Correct Values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    progressDialog.show();
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    joinVerify(true);
                }
            }
        });



private void joinVerify(Boolean isJoined) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), mobile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mobile).child("wallet");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                ivalue = Integer.parseInt(value);

                if (tcmoney > ivalue) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Insufficient Funds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    if(isJoined){
                         int ijoin = ivalue - tcmoney;
                        String join = String.valueOf(ijoin);

                        databaseReference.setValue(join);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Joined Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        isJoined = false

                    }
                   


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: While indeed it may well be that you've identified the problem here, can you expand your answer to explain how your code addresses the problem?

Comment: once ValueEventListener() is called it remains activated. for every change/update made at Realtime database. Where onDataChange get called.

Comment: And how does the code in your answer fix that problem?

Comment: I'm just trying to update value only once, only when button is clicked. By passing the boolean value. May be the boolean value must be global variable? can you point where I'm getting the cause?

Comment: @charlie.7 Thanks Charlie for figure out the issue this code works for me. I really stuck in this problem for more than a week and also thankyou for explaining how you found this issue.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thankyou for try to resolve my issue and comment Have a nice day :D